# How to rearrange date and time

Tags: r

Could you please tell me how to rearrange the datetime of data set A in order to compatible with datetime of data set B (which is in GMT+10 format)?
    Thank you.

```
**data set A**

sitecode status  start                           end
ANS0009  spike   11/09/2013 04:45:00 PM (GMT+11) 11/09/2013 05:00:00 PM (GMT+11)
ARM0064  spike   05/03/2014 11:00:00 AM (GMT+10) 05/03/2014 11:15:00 AM (GMT+10)
BAS0059  dry     13/01/2013 00:00:00 AM (GMT+11) 29/03/2013 11:45:00 PM (GMT+11)
BAS0059  spike   11/03/2014 10:15:00 AM (GMT+10) 11/03/2014 10:30:00 AM (GMT+10)
BLC0097  failure 12/20/2012 05:00:00 PM (GMT+11) 12/31/2012 11:45:00 PM (GMT+11)
BLC0097  spike   24/12/2015 04:59:45 PM (GMT+10) 24/12/2015 05:01:50 PM (GMT+10)


**data set B**

sitecode  status               start                 end
EUM0056  record   2012-12-01 11:00:00   2013-10-06 01:45:00
EUM0056 missing   2013-10-06 01:45:00   2013-10-06 03:00:00
EUM0056  record   2013-10-06 03:00:00   2014-03-11 20:15:00
MDL0026  record   2012-12-07 11:00:00   2013-04-04 19:45:00
MDL0026 missing   2013-04-04 19:45:00   2014-02-27 23:00:00
MDL0026  record   2014-02-27 23:00:00   2014-10-05 01:45:00
```

Comment: Your dates are also all over the place. In `A` - `12/20/2012` on one line, which must be `m/d/y` logically. Then `24/12/2015` on the next line, which must be `d/m/y`.

Comment: @thelatemail Maybe that's just part of the challenge. It happens a lot in the real world when you have to combine dates in string format from different database tables or data sources. For instance if the timestamps for some records were generated by some Perl script and others by SalesForce or Apache, then all of this data got piped into MySQL and joined together by some query.

Comment: @Hack-R - it might be part of the challenge, but it's virtually impossible to distinguish. Is `6/12/2000` 12th June or 6th December? There's no way to know without knowing the source of the data.

Answer (score 0):

We can could use `lubridate` to parse multiple formats after splitting the string into two to remove the `(GMT + ...)`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
v1 <- strsplit(str1, "\\s+(?=\\()", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
parse_date_time(v1[1], c("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
          tz= "GMT", exact = TRUE) + lubridate::hours(str_extract(v1[2], "\\d+"))
#[1] "2013-09-12 03:45:00 GMT"
```

---

Using the full dataset example

```
datA[c("start", "end")] <-  lapply(datA[c("start", "end")], function(x){
       m1 <-  do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, "\\s+(?=\\()", perl = TRUE))
      parse_date_time(m1[,1], c("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
       tz = "GMT", exact = TRUE) + lubridate::hours(str_extract(m1[,2], "\\d+")
    )})
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "11/09/2013 04:45:00 PM (GMT+11)"
```

Comment: He also has to change the timezone for certain rows. His 2nd data set was GMT + 10 and his first was a mix of GMT+10 and GMT+11. I dealt with this by creating a flag using `grepl` then changing the timezone after conversion to a date format, but there may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(lubridate)

exampleA <- c("11/09/2013 04:45:00 PM (GMT+11)",
              "11/09/2013 04:45:00 PM (GMT+10)")
exampleA      <- as.data.frame(exampleA)
exampleA$flag <- 0
exampleA$flag[grep(" PM \\(GMT\\+11\\)", exampleA$exampleA)] <- 1
exampleA$exampleA <- gsub(" PM \\(GMT\\+11\\)","", exampleA$exampleA)
exampleA$exampleA <- gsub(" PM \\(GMT\\+10\\)","", exampleA$exampleA)
exampleA$exampleA <- mdy_hms(exampleA$exampleA)
exampleA$exampleA[exampleA$flag == 1] <- exampleA$exampleA - 3600

exampleB <- c("2013-11-09 03:45:00", "2013-11-09 04:45:00")
exampleB <- ymd_hms(exampleB)

# Proof it works
exampleA$exampleA == exampleB
```

> [1] TRUE TRUE

If you have a mix of formats in 1 data set (i.e. mdy, ydm, etc) you can deal with this by using `if` statements -- either in a function which you can `apply` or a `for` loop -- and text `if` a certain position has a value `>12` to determine the format, then use the appropriate `lubridate` function to convert it.